# General convergence of Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

This is to be proven or disproven:

Be $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a real sequence with $a_n \geq 0$ $ \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$. Then, if $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k$ converges for n$\to \infty$ also $\sum_{k=0}^{n} a^2_k$ convergese for n$\to \infty$.

The opposite direction is not true (a counterexample would be $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2}$) but im not certain how it is for the stated direction. My first thought was to argue with the necessary convergence criterion ($a_k$ needs to be a zero-sequence): Since $a_k$ needs to be a zero-sequence, there exists a $n_0$, so that for all $n \geq n_0$ there is true: $a_n < 1$. Then for all $a_n$ satisfying that follows $a^2_n < a_n$ because $x^2 < x$ for all $0 < x < 1$ with $x \in\mathbb{R}$. That means a fulfillment of the comparison test since $a^2_n < a_n$ will be true for sufficiently large n.

Is that a correct proof or am i missing something (does a counterexample exist)?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I also say correct

Comment: In fact, the following is also true. If $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, then $\sum a^2_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, as convergence implies $a_n\searrow 0$. Hence, there exists $N\geq 0$ such that for $n\geq N$ $0 \leq a_n \leq 1$, and thus
$$
0 \leq a_n^2 \leq a_n
$$
You can then conclude by comparison theorems.

Note that the hypothesis that $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be non-negative is paramount; it is no longer true otherwise (e.g., consider the converging series defined by $a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$).